# How to set textBox to automatically convert number to double

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, double

My question is: how can I set textbox to automatically convert a number to double when you click another textbox?.

For example: As shown in screen shot, I click button1 to enter 1 into textbox1 and when you click textbox2, the 1 will be converted to 1.00 in textbox1. And enter 12 into textbox1 then it will be converted to 12.00 when you click textbox2.

Now the problem is:  I insert 1 in textbox1 and when I insert 2 into textbox1 (it should be 12) the textbox deletes the 1 and inserts 2. Now textbox1 only contains number 2 and when I click on textbox2 the textbox1 converts 2 to 2.00

I mean I want to form number 12 by clicking on button1 and then button2 but I can not because I insert 1 and when I insert 2 the previous 1 is deleted. I think this happens because the `textBox1_Leave` method gets executed when I click on button2. 
I don't know How to fix it.

I just want textbox1 to convert the any entered number to double when textbox2 is clicked. I hope I explained it well, please help me. Thank you

[image: Screen shot]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private TextBoxBase SelectedBox = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();  //set textbox1 focused when form loads
        SelectedBox = textBox1;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedBox.Focus(); // set the current textbox focused.

        SendKeys.Send("1");

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedBox.Focus();

        SendKeys.Send("2");

    }

    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) // to set focus textbox1
    {
        SelectedBox = sender as TextBox;
        this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
        textBox1.Focus();

    }

    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)// to set focus textbox2
    {
        SelectedBox = sender as TextBox;
        this.ActiveControl = textBox2;
        textBox2.Focus();
    }



    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)   // to convert any number in textbox1 to double once textbox2 is clicked
    {
        double d = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = d.ToString("0.00");
        SelectedBox = sender as TextBox;

    }
}
```

Comment: Try going to the properties of the TextBox -> Databindings -> Advanced -> Choose the formatting type.

Comment: @austin wernli . I went there but the format type is disabled. any idea why? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method as the handler for `Leave` event of your text boxes

```
private void ChangeToDoubleWhenLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        double value;
        if (double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value))
        {
            textBox.Text = value.ToString("F");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I placed this method inside the Leave event of texbox1 but still same problem. I insert 1 in textbox1 and when I insert 2 into textbox1 (it should be 12) the textbox deletes the 1 and inserts 2. Now textbox1 only contains number 2 and when I click on textbox2 the textbox1 converts 2 to 2.00.  can you help please? thank you

Comment: you should remove this line! `textBox1.Text = d.ToString("0.00");`

Comment: yes I already  did remove everything in the Leave event and placed your method but the problem still there. can I just take 3 mins from your time and try it in your laptop if it is possible? I have spent hours to solve it but I failed. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 void textBox1_textchange(object sender, EventArgs e) // to set focus textbox1
    {
        if(textBox1.focused() && textBox1.Text.toString()!="")
            TextBox2.Text=Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text).to string();

     }



 void textBox2_textchange(object sender, EventArgs e) // to set focus textbox1
    {
        if(textBox2.focused() && textBox2.Text.toString()!="")
            TextBox1.Text=Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text).to string();

     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok I solved this problem after spending over 2 hours.

remove the textBox1_Leave event, and add the following code in textBox2_Enter event.

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Text = d.ToString("0.00");
```